# Search Application Topology, moving the Query Component and get a Crawl component error

Tags: search

I am changing the Server Farm to a 3-tier topology and want to change the Query Component to run on the Web Server.

When I change the Search Service Application Topology for the Query Component to run on the Web Server and not on the Application Server then I get the following error:

Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application.

Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard+SearchConfigWizardException:  Topology provisioning failed due to an error.Crawl component '.....' on Server cannot be dismounted.  Check that the server is available. at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.WaitForTopologyTimerJobToFinish() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.UpdateSearchApp() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.ProvisionSearchServiceApplication() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchConfigWizard.ExecuteTimerJob()
Date & Time

I did run the "net start SPTimerV4" command in command prompt on the servers. The Query Component stays on the initializing Status and I keep on getting this error.

Please help?!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, moving search components through UI is problematic because it doesn't seem to include a shutdown of the service and I've never been able to get it to work right without the -force parameter... See article for moving search admin service, for query component just sun in the component name.

http://iedaddy.com/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-migrating-search-admin-to-different-servers-in-the-farm/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what went wrong with the settings.  I uninstalled SharePoint on all the Servers, deleted the databases in the SQL database.

Then I re-installed and I could move the Query Component as I tried before, this time no error!!